# Import weatherdata as csv in OpenModelica

Tags: csv, openmodelica, datasheet

For a energy model I have to integrate weatherdata into my OpenModelica model. The data I have is a csv data with 9 columns and several hundreds of rows ... for specific classes I need one or more columns of the datasheet. Is it posible to translate my Matlab skript to OpenModelica?
This is my working Matlab skript:

```
Temperatur = csvread('Wetterdaten\TemperaturSPO3.csv');

Jahr_Temp = Temperatur(:,2); % Year 12/1999 bis 12/2016
Monat_Temp = Temperatur(:,3); % Month
Tag_Temp = Temperatur(:,4);
Stunde_Temp= Temperatur(:,5);
T = Temperatur(:,7); %Temperature 
RF = Temperatur(:,8); %air moisture
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you want to do with the data, or the exact data format.  But, you should be able to do this using the [CombiTimeTable](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable.html) block if you can get the time data in the right format, or one of the other [block tables](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Blocks.Tables.html): CombiTable1D, CombiTable1Ds, or CombiTable2D depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  These blocks can have the data embedded, in a text file, or in a MAT file, so you should be able to use your matlab data file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

## modelica file

```
input Real Jahr_Temp;
input Real Monat_Temp;
input Real Tag_Temp;
input Real Stunde_Temp;
input Real T;
input Real RF;
```

## mos scripte

```
loadFile("MyModel.mo");
simulate(MyPacakge.MyModel, simflags="-csvInput Wetterdaten\TemperaturSPO3.csv"
```

Note csvInput use the table header for map inputs with csv file, default delimiter  is withespace